# Access DataRefreshSchedule via C# using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am currently building C# applications that talk to SharePoint 2013 using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.

One requirement I have is to access Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SharePoint.Integration.DataRefreshSchedule to change this. Searching through google I have found a couple of solutions that use the old Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll which does not help me.

The first part of this solution runs the following:
    (GeminiServiceApplicationProxy)SPServiceContext.GetContext(sPSite).GetDefaultProxy(typeof(GeminiServiceApplicationProxy))

Put simply I'd like to run this using ClientContext instead. A command like:

```
ClientContext c = get the context

c.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(GeminiServiceApplicationProxy))
```

Alas I cannot see a way to do this.

I have two key questions:

1. How can i access the DataRefreshSchedule using ClientContext or
2. How can I get the default proxy using ClientContext.